# Does OpenStack support jumbo frame internal networks over a physical network without jumbo frame support?

Tags: openstack, ping

There are 2 VMs deployed in two different compute nodes in an Openstack environment.
Interfaces of the VMs [configured with 9K MTU] are connected via switch [configured with 9K MTU].

ping with jumbo frame [without fragment] is not working between these two VMs.

`ping <IP Address> -I <Interface Name> -s 8972 -M do`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No. If physical switch between computes is not configured for jumbo frame
>   support then switch would simply drop these packets.

You need to configure all physical devices in between to have jumbo frame support (like switch and compute node NIC card).

Comment: I've configured MTU of -
    1. interface of the VMs
    2. interface of the hosts
    3. switch in-between

Did I miss something ?